# I dont know how to sum expenses based on category in sequelize

Tags: mysql, express, chart.js, sequelize.js, vue-chartjs

I've got my expense-tracker app. There are three tables - User,Expense,Category. Each Expense model has name,date,categoryId,amonut.
There is a REST API(ExpressJS+Sequelize+MySQL) which I consume with Vuejs app on client side.
I want to add charts to my app.

I dont know how to to return sum of Expenses for each category.
There is some 'sum' function in Sequelize, but how use it to expose in API sum of expense for each category?

I try something like this:

```
router.get('/sum', function(req,res,next){
Expense.sum('amount', { where: {date: {} }})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this -

```
Expense.findAll({
    attributes : ['categoryId', [db.sequelize.fn('SUM', db.sequelize.col('amount')), 'total']],
    group : ['categoryId']
});
```

This will result in list of categories with their sum. You can apply other aggregate function too.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately your code doesnt work. This is my route for expenses: https://pastebin.com/A1CyhFXB

Comment: In the console there is some error about coding the ASCII signs. Maybe the route should be named in specified way?